# Symfony Doctrine admin generator and I18n: error when cache is empty

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a strange error in an admin module created by the admin generator: 
My model has the following shema:

```
StmtcHelp:
  columns:
    module: { type: string(255) }
    action: { type: string(255) }
    content: { type: string(10000) }
    translated: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: false }
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    I18n:
      fields: [content, translated]
```

My generator.yml:

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           stmtcHelp
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          stmtc_help
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions:
        _delete:
          credentials: [is_super_admin]
        _new:
          credentials: [is_super_admin]
        _create:
          credentials: [is_super_admin]
      fields:  ~
      list:
        title: Inline Help
        display: [ module, action, updated_at ]
      filter:
        display: [ module, action ]
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

Now I clear the cache and load the stmtc_help/index action, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's.content' in 'field list'. 
Failing Query: "SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.module AS s__module, s.action AS s__action, 
s.content AS s__content, s.translated AS s__translated, s.created_at AS s__created_at, 
s.updated_at AS s__updated_at FROM stmtc_help s LIMIT 20"
```

It seems that Doctrine don't recognize my model as I18n.

But if I reload the page, the error disappear, all works fine.

Does anybody have had this kind of issue? What am I missing?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.
Your `model_class` parameter in `generator.yml` is set to `stmtcHelp` but your model name is `StmtcHelp` (the first letter is uppercase). Fix this one and check `routing.yml` for the same problem.
In my case I had my model misspelled only in `routing.yml` and it caused the same `Column not found` error.